# Is there a way to use 7zFM.exe for file splitting on Windows cmd without opening GUI or use 7za.exe to split files faster as same as 7zFM.exe

Tags: command-line-interface, 7zip

7zFm.exe splits files faster than 7za.exe

This entire process is in WINDOWS OPERATING SYSTEM

I am splitting a file using the 7zip.After a lot of R&D I found that if you want to use 7zip via command line you need to use the 7zip standalone version which is 7za.exe and if you want to use it through a GUI you need use the 7zip software which is 7zFM.exe

When I tried splitting the file using the 7za.exe via the command line using the following syntax

`
"C:\EXE_LOCATION\7za.exe" a -v2m -mx=1,-mmt=off "Release4.zip" "*.xlsm"

```
EXE_LOCATION = Full path of 7za.exe on the computer
a = create archive(=zip)
-v2m = split the file into 2MB
"Release4.zip" = zip output file name
```

"*.xlsm" = source file name(s) to zip
`

it took 10-12 minutes to split (It was used in Fast mode by giving these two -mx=1,-mmt=off(optional))

when I used the 7zFM.exe it opened a GUI and after passing the parameters it took 5-6 minutes split the same file and I tried to execute the 7zFM.exe through command line but still it kept opening its GUI.

Side Note:
I even used 7zG.exe in the command line it also opens the GUI and I used 7z.exe in command line it in the fast mode(-mx=1,-mmt=off) and it took 13 minutes

My Problem:
How to make 7za split faster or take the same time as 7zFM.exe to split the file or use 7zFM.exe via command line without making it open GUI and split the files